# Placing a triangle around nodes in a tree

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a tree filled with numbers and I want to mark a subtree by drawing a triangle around it. I can't seem to get it working.

My attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {3};

\node (7) at (-1/2,-1) {7};
\node at (1/2,-1) {4};

\node at (-1,-2) {2};
\node at (0,-2) {4};
\node at (1,-2) {6};

\node (8) at (-3/2,-3) {8};
\node at (-1/2,-3) {5};
\node (9) at (1/2,-3) {9};
\node at (3/2,-3) {3};

\node[isosceles triangle,fit = (7) (8) (9)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, `fit` library only works with `rectangle` and `ellipse`. You can draw an isosceles triangle, but not with fit.

Comment: You should first add `draw` option to your last node. Then notice that the triangle is too big. It might be much more precise if you just do it manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to explicitly add the `draw` option (red triangle) to use `fit` library, or you could use the `calc` and `pgf` library to compute vertices of the triangle (blue triangle):

[image]
[image]

---

### Code: `draw` option:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {3};

\node (7) at (-1/2,-1) {7};
\node at (1/2,-1) {4};

\node at (-1,-2) {2};
\node at (0,-2) {4};
\node at (1,-2) {6};

\node (8) at (-3/2,-3) {8};
\node at (-1/2,-3) {5};
\node (9) at (1/2,-3) {9};
\node at (3/2,-3) {3};

\node[isosceles triangle,fit = (7) (8) (9),draw=red,thick] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: Computed Vertices:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,fit, calc}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\sinOffset}{sin(60)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cosOffset}{cos(60)}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {3};

\node (7) at (-1/2,-1) {7};
\node at (1/2,-1) {4};

\node at (-1,-2) {2};
\node at (0,-2) {4};
\node at (1,-2) {6};

\node (8) at (-3/2,-3) {8};
\node at (-1/2,-3) {5};
\node (9) at (1/2,-3) {9};
\node at (3/2,-3) {3};

\draw [blue, thick] 
    ($(7)+(0,1)$) -- 
    ($(8)+(-\sinOffset,-\cosOffset)$) -- 
    ($(9)+( \sinOffset,-\cosOffset)$) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Peter A little remark : i't not useful to load `pgf.sty` before `tikz` because the first line of this file is `\RequirePackage{pgf,pgffor}` and for your example "Computed Vertices", only the library `calc` is used.

Comment: @Altermundus: Thanks.Have removed the `pgf` package from 2nd example.

Comment: one can use `(210:1)` instead of `(-\sinOffset,-\cosOffset)` and `(-30:1)` instead of `( \sinOffset,-\cosOffset)`